# webpack failing to compile in a react app

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I'm trying do configure webpack in a react project created without create-react-app, 
I have this error when I run npm run webpack.

```
8.78 KiB    main  [emitted]  main
Entrypoint main = bundle.js
[./lib/app.js] 4.7 KiB {main} [built] [failed] [1 error]

ERROR in ./lib/app.js
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js):
SyntaxError: /Users/code/react-advanced/lib/app.js: Unexpected token (5:2)

  3 | 
  4 | const App = () => {
> 5 |   <h2>Hello there!</h2>;
    |   ^
  6 | };
  7 | ReactDom.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

webpack.config.js :

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: './lib/app.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'public')
  },
  module: {
    rules: [{ test: /\.(js|jsx)$/, use: 'babel-loader' }]
  }
};
```

package.json :

```
"dependencies": {
"@babel/core": "^7.8.3",
"babel": "^6.23.0",
"babel-cli": "^6.26.0",
"babel-eslint": "^10.0.3",
"babel-loader": "^8.0.6",
"babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.24.1",
"babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
"babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
"express": "^4.17.1",
"nodemon": "^2.0.2",
"prettier": "^1.19.1",
"react": "^16.12.0",
"react-dom": "^16.12.0",
"webpack": "^4.41.5",
"webpack-cli": "^3.3.10"


},
```

what could be wrong ??

Comment: add return before your `h2`

Comment: tryed and not fixing the problem @GBWDev

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hint is in what the cursor is pointing at in the error message:

```
SyntaxError: /Users/code/react-advanced/lib/app.js: Unexpected token (5:2)

  3 | 
  4 | const App = () => {
> 5 |   <h2>Hello there!</h2>;
    |   ^
```

Notice on line 5 there is an arrow pointing at the JSX `<h2>` tag.

The problem is that Babel doesn't understand JSX on its own.

You need to add the [React preset](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-react) manually for it to do so.

1. First install `@babel/preset-react`:

   ```
   npm install --save-dev @babel/preset-react
   ```
2. Then tell Babel about it by updating your webpack config (or creating a Babel configuration file next to your webpack config):

   ```
   module: {
     rules: [{
       test: /\.(js|jsx)$/,
       use: {
         loader: 'babel-loader',
         options: {
           presets: ['@babel/preset-react']
         }
       }
     }]
   }
   ```

Read more here:

- https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-react
- https://webpack.js.org/loaders/babel-loader/

---

As an aside, you need to return your `h2` element from `App`:

```
const App = () => {
   return <h2>Hello there!</h2>;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In `React`, component's should return something that can be rendered. In your scenario you are missing a `return` statement in your `app.js`.

```
const App = () => {
   return <h2>Hello there!</h2>;
};
```